# Prove that all $c_i=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Let $A_1,A_2,...,A_r$ Some non-zero vectors in $\mathbb R^n$ such that $A_i\cdot A_j=0$ for all $i\ne j$.

Let $c,...,c_r$ some real numbers such that $$c_1A_1+c_2A_2+\cdots+c_rA_r=0$$

Prove that all $c_i=0$

First it is more simple to work with the special case $r=2$, then since $A_1\cdot A_2=0$ Then there is no such $c_1,c_2\in \mathbb R^2$ such that $$c_1A_1+c_2A_2=0$$ except for the case where $c_1=c_2=0$.

This last statement has to formalize in a more rigorous way, but i don’t how to do it i’ve just an intuition that this is the right case, and for higher dimensional vector this intuition would disappear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the properties of the dot product:

$$\begin{aligned}
c_1A_1+c_2A_2+\cdots+c_rA_r=0\quad&\Rightarrow\quad (c_1A_1+c_2A_2+\cdots+c_rA_r)\cdot A_1=0\cdot A_1\\\\
&\Rightarrow \quad c_1A_1\cdot A_1+c_2A_2\cdot A_1+\cdots+c_rA_r\cdot A_1=0
\\\\&\Rightarrow \quad c_1=0
\end{aligned}$$

Analogously, taking the dot product of the original equality with $A_2, ..., A_r$, we conclude that $c_2=0, ...,c_r=0$

Answer (score 0):

$$c_i ||A_i||^2 =A_i \cdot \sum_{j=1}^r c_j A_j =A_i \cdot 0 =0$$